# php - get value from variable

Tags: php, sql, sqlanywhere

I need to take value form variable, hode one part and send the other part in email.

This variable is [sql anywhere](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/sqlanywhere) query result.

This is what i have so far:

```
$res=sqlanywhere_query(...)

$resID=explode('#',$res);
$email.=$email_footer.$resID[1].$email_footer2;
```

When I had in email `$res`, in email I get something liike `Resource #163`.

When I put `$resID[1]`, in place where should be `163`, space was empty.

Comment: What is the output of `print_r($resID)` ?

Comment: `Resource #163` means it is a resource object, you need to fetch data from it.

Comment: I think `sqlanywhere_fetch_array` should work, I didn't though about that. I can't test it right now because machine where sqlanywhere is is off, but it should be ok. Thanks for help all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because your `$res` is a resource, you have to get the results.
You should have for that library something like

```
$sql = sqlanywhere_query(...)
$res = sqlanywhere_fetch($sql);
```

and `$res` will be an array with your query result;

Answer (score 1):

It's a resource, which means that it's a special variable that holds a reference to an external source.

See the PHP manual on [Resources](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php).

Answer (score 1):

please, using database with php. when you query, you must pass the result to a fetch function before you can access the values.

```
$res=sqlanywhere_query(...)

//fetch one
$data = sqlanywhere_fetch_row($res)

// or u loop through
while($row = sqlanywhere_fetch_row($res))
{
    echo $row["id"];
}
```

all these functiosn are deprecated. you can use mysql_query and mysql_fetch_row (or other fetch functions).
you can also use mysqli_ functions. read PHP manual.

hope it helps